# Can I use Spring JdbcTemplate in Spring Batch Job Implementation?

Tags: spring-batch

As per the Spring Batch Documentation, it provides the variety of flavors to read data from the database as `ItemReader`. In my case, there are lots of business validation needs to be performed against the database. 
Let's say after reading data from any of the below source, I wanted to validate them against the multiple databases, Can I use Spring `JdbcTemplate` in Spring Batch Job Implementation?

```
 1. HibernatePagingItemReader 
 2. HibernateCursorItemReader
 3. JpaPagingItemReader 
 4. JdbcPagingItemReader
 5. JdbcCursorItemReader
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever mechanism you desire including `JdbcTemplate` to read database with Spring Batch. Spring Batch as a framework doesn't put any such restrictions.

Spring Batch has those convenient readers ( listed by you ) for simple use cases and if those don't fit in your requirement, you are very free to write your own readers too.

`JdbcPagingItemReader` itself uses a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` created on datasource that you provide.

You requirement is not very clear to me but I guess, you can do any of the two tasks,

1.**Composite Reader** - You write your own composite reader and use one of Spring Batch readers as first reader then put in validation logic on those read items

2.**Validate in Processor** - Read your items with Spring Batch provided readers then process / validate in processor. Chaining of processors is possible in Spring Batch - [Chaining ItemProcessors](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#chainingItemProcessors) so you can put different transformations if different processors and produce a final output after a chain.

Comment: Thank You, Yes, Spring Batch as a framework doesn't put any such restrictions but I had confusion that whether it is a good approach or best practices or not. Thanks for your reply.